# select minimum value price ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my view index, which shown prices for my items.

```
      <% for import_price in ItemImportPrice.find(:all,
         :conditions => ['itemCode = ? and beginDate = ?', item.short_name, item_days.day) ], 
                                         :order => ['price asc']) %>
          <%= import_price.price %>  
          <%= import_price.superItemType %>
          ...
      <% end %>
```

In the view I have the following result:

```
89.0     I 
99.0     I 
109.0    I 
119.0    I 
129.0    I 
129.0    O
139.0    O
149.0    O 
159.0    O
439.0    B
459.0    B
529.0    D 
849.0    D 
949.0    D
```

How to do so would shown only minimal price for superItemType (I, O, B, D)?

If I add :group => "superStateroomType" it displays 4 items, but prices not minimal.

P.S. May be do this method, but I do not know how to apply it for all...

```
ItemImportPrice.all(:select => "Min(price) as min_price", :conditions => ["itemCode = ? and beginDate = ?", item.short_name, item_days.day]).first.min_price
```

Comment: please check the documentation for minimum function in rails 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-minimum

Comment: Why are you putting all this logic into your view?

Comment: because item.short_name and item_days.day are defined only in view

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with

```
ItemImportPrice.select('MIN(price) AS min_price, superItemType').group('superItemType')
```

Comment: this method error "private method `select' called for #<Class:0x7fd0dfdc8360>" p.s. rails 2.3 ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

ItemImportPrice.all(:select => "superItemType, Min(price) as min_price", :conditions => ["itemCode = ? and beginDate = ?", item.short_name, item_days.day], :group =>"superItemType").first.min_price